# Top pixels dont have the correct backgroundcolor in UiTableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a strange problem with my tableviewcell. I use the follwing code to color my selected cell.

```
 self.backgroundColor = [UIColor greyColor];
```

[image]

As you can see in the attached image, the first pixel line is still white.
The problem only appears on cell 2 and below if the first cell is selected, everything looks good.
Does anyone have a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the `separatorStyle` property of `UITableView` to `UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleSingleLine`